# Is it possible to check a bag for only the second leg of the flight?

Tags: transit, luggage, lhr, check-in

I am stopping over in LHR and meeting a friend from the uk for the connecting flight to the US. I am wondering if it is possible for me to check in a bag in london if i dont chck one in for the first leg?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  In most cases you just ask the Agent to Gate Check the bag.

Keep in mind, it will be delivered to your last destination only.  You cannot collect it at a connecting point.